# My Ubuntu 12.04 Installation hangs after "Preparing to install Ubuntu". What can I do to work around the problem?

Tags: 12.04, system-installation

I did download Ubuntu 12.04LTS. I tried to install - no progress. I tried to remove all partition using a bootable version of GParted. I created one big partition ext4 formatted. It all did not help. The installation stops after "Preparing to install Ubuntu". All three checkmarks are checked an I can click "Continue" but then nothing for hours.
What can I do? Please help!

Comment: Are you installing from a bootable thumb drive? I had this very same issue about a year ago, the last time I re-installed my desktop, and it was solved by burning the image to a DVD, instead of using a bootable thumb drive. I hope this helps you. :)

Comment: I am booting from a DVD drive. I created a DVD with Ubuntu 12.04 installation iso image on it. So sorry - this was the way I already tried...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks KodduX and Jonathan Acosta - you brought me to the right track!!!

I did three things and in combination they worked. Actually I don't know which of those (or the combination) made the big difference.

As it did not work from CD, I made a bootable USB stick and started from there (opposite of what worked for Jonathan)
I started with the "try out" (like suggested from KodduX - Thanks!!) version and there click on Install Ubuntu
I did uncheck the two checkboxes (Update from Internet and install software) - with those checekd it did not work

Thanks for all that helped!!!