# Ubuntu LiveCd hangs on boot screen

Tags: boot, live-cd

Every time I try to install or try Ubuntu I hit the [booting screen](http://linoob.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Ubuntu-Bootscreen.png)  and it hangs there forever.

I've never had any issues installing Ubuntu.

Currently I've tried putting Ubuntu on a live USB(multiple writing softwares) and using live CD.

I've tried different computers but this one is the only one that failed to boot up.

Also the computer will install windows from an install CD perfectly.

I've tried booting with the following settings.

- Acpi = off
- noapic
- nolapic
- nomodeset

Again nothing worked. I've also tried several distros and encountered similar problems.

Is there something I could have missed here because I've hit a brick wall at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

Well. There are really a number of reasons that your installation can stall. I stumbled upon your question while looking for an answer to my own current (and also first) Ubuntu installation problem.

I'm not versed well enough in Ubuntu (nor Linux in general) to be able to give your direct tips -- but I'll share some of my findings (some of which I have tried, others not):

1) See if your hardware is Linux/Ubuntu compatible. Here's for checking general [Linux compatibility](http://www.linuxcompatible.org/). See also [Ubuntu Hardware support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/) section in Ubuntu.com wiki.

... Now, I can't share more links in this answer as the Fabulous StackExchange system is limiting my links to 2 (due to my lacking reputation points). More in another answer. (and GRRrr. to CrapExchange for the dorky limitations).

Comment: ((Trying to add links here if that would work...))
Some more similarish issues: http://askubuntu.com/questions/501459/ubuntu-installer-hangs and http://www.linux.org/threads/freeze-while-installation-xubuntu-ubuntu-knoppix.7085/

Answer (score 1):

So, continuing with more pointers:

2) Look at various installation issue options: e.g. 
[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Got freezing while preparing to install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252292/ubuntu-12-04-lts-got-freezing-while-preparing-to-install) , its duplicate (but with some good comments) [My Ubunto 12.04 Installation hangs after "Preparing to install Ubuntu". What can I do to work around the problem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432401/my-ubunto-12-04-installation-hangs-after-preparing-to-install-ubuntu-what-can) , ((hitting the link limit again...))

As you can see it's a good idea to report your setup as well as possible. That helps in providing advice. At least list what computer you have (problems with) and what are the exact distros and their versions that you've tried.

Example: I've been trying to install Ubuntu 15.04, 14.04 and 14.04.2 (and both amd64 and x86 versions) as well as lubuntu 14.04.2 (OSGeo Live 8.5 package) on my Lenovo W540 but have had similar problems as you. 
(As noted I haven't yet tried all the tips from the links I posted above).

Answer (score -1):

I left mine doing the red dot thing for about 50 minutes then the DVD drive whirled into action and voilà desktop arrives.